# Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 With Autofac 3.5.2

Tags: aop, autofac, interception

I have 2 projects in my solution.

One uses `Autofac 3.5.2` and the other is used `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 for interception (Autofac 3.3.1).`
The one with `Autofac 3.3.1` has project reference to the one with `Autofac 3.5.2`.
Trying to run different `dll` versions in my solution fails, while upgrading `3.3.1 to 3.5.2` skips interceptor logic.

I would like to run interception on `Autofac 3.5.2` since I use 3.5.2 on many other project I develop.

Did someone faced this issue with success?

Thank you

The error I get is:
Error   5   Assembly ' , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'

Comment: What is the error you have? Any error message?

Comment: @CyrilDurand I added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *assemblyBinding*:

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" 
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```